# DotNetNuke (DNN) 1 module - 3 ASCX files scenario

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-imc

I am new to DNN. I have created a DNN module with three controls (C#, .NET3.5) :

- Controller
- EmailRequest
- DealSuccess

`Controller` checks `["ClientEmail"]` cookie value AND if `NULL` redirects to `EmailRequest` control, if `NOT NULL` redirects to `DealSuccess` control.

I need to wire these components in DNN. I have decided to create separate pages for `EmailRequest`, `DealSuccess`.

Associating these controls and their respective pages, including building/assigning URLs and calling them, is bit ambiguous because some of that needs to be done in DNN configuration and some in code.

Answer (score 0):

According to your reply yesterday, my reply to your forum post clarified this for you

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/201/postid/439089/scope/posts.aspx#439089